# Laravel 5 having to send token with all requests in KendoUI Grid

Tags: php, laravel, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, laravel-5

I'm having to send the _token with every grid operation (except for read) in my kendo grid, otherwise I get a token mismatch error:

```
...
transport: {
            read: {
                url: '/core/income-grid/read',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'get'
            },
            update: {
                url: '/core/income-grid/update',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                data: function(data){
                    data._token = $('#incomeGrid').data('csrf');
                    return data;
                }
            },
            create: {
                url: '/core/income-grid/create',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                data: function(data){
                    data._token = $('#incomeGrid').data('csrf');
                    return data;
                }
            },
            destroy: {
                url: '/core/income-grid/destroy',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                data: function(data){
                    data._token = $('#incomeGrid').data('csrf');
                    return data;
                }
            }
        },
...
```

Is there a way to get around this and still have the protection the csrf token provides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have CSRF protection in Laravel without a token being passed.

However, according to the [Kendo UI Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) there is a method called `transport.parameterMap` which allows the manipulation of the request parameters. This should allow you to include the token as a parameter for all non-read requests in one place, instead of having to specify it for all operations individually:

```
transport: {
    ...,
    parameterMap: function(data, type)
    {
        if (type !== "read")
            data._token = $('#incomeGrid').data('csrf');

        return data;
    }
}
```